# Cannot connect to internet when sign and run from simulator to real Blackberry devices

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I have got one problem about internet connection in real devices. I develop my Blackberry chat application using Eclipse JDE and it run smoothly on Blackberry Simulator (OS: 4.7, 5.0 and 6.0). But when I sign it and install it in a real device. It always states: "No internet connection". I've check my wifi and GPRS connection and it works fine.

Are there any adjustments for internet application developed using simulator deployed on a real devices?

Comment: Your app states "no internet connection"?
Post how you check for it.

Comment: Are you aware of BB Network Transports? Without your code that opens a connection posted here it's hard to advise you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the code we can’t find the actual reason of this issue. Still let me tell you about the a common reason

In the connection string depending on the state add interface = wifi or deviceside = true.

```
HttpConnection connection = null;
if (WLANInfo.getWLANState() == WLANInfo.WLAN_STATE_CONNECTED) {
connection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url+ ";interface=wifi",
Connector.READ_WRITE,true);
} else {
connection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url+";deviceside=true", Connector.READ_WRITE,true);
}
```